# Why are there vague terms in science and mathematics?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, mathematics, scientific-language

In the sciences and in mathematics there are a great number of words and terms in use that do not, in any literal sense, describe the concept they are meant to describe.

Let's explore the use of "reaction" as it used in chemistry or physics: Yes yes, we all know the commonly USED meanings of the word. We can and do *infer rather than decode* all the time. That "re" prefix seems to just be crazy to use if you're wanting to be accurate - which I assume is important to most scientists. So why is inferred meaning OK in this case? Wouldn't using a word that, when decoded, actually defined the thing be *better* for scientists to do, even if that word was relegated to science and was not in common use in the general public? But scientists *do* use it to mean "interact" as well as "re-act" (act again) and also "a series of interactions" and "the results of *n* interactions"...

Another one to explore is the term "irrational number" - which i know has its own questions in these stacks but not in the same context as my question. When you look at the etymology of it it sure seems to me that early USE of the term for maths (as the originators of the concept groped for greek words to describe it) led to our modern definition: 'not able to be represented as a ratio'. Past a certain point going back in time it was really just referencing rationality of thought. But, mathematicians have so long used it that it has actually morphed meaning. On it's own, morphing is no biggie, languages change, word use changes yadda yadda. But in a field where clarity and precision are so very important, it seems really *weird* that the term survives in this sense. Why has a term not been created to separate the two ideas, rationality of thought vs ratio-ABILITY of numbers?

There are only two examples - there are so many more.

And to be honest here, this strange use of English within mathematics is the *primary* reason I found maths so challenging when I was young... None of the words used to describe the numbers and what the numbers were doing made any logical connection to what was actually being done with them!

EDIT: To clarify part of what I'm getting at here - a base tenet of science and maths is the formulation, testing, and modification of hypotheses. Yet that approach is not taken with the English usage. It is never asked "we began using this term because we were struggling to describe *X* - but why are we still using it when we know it to be inadequate?" We would not continue to use a theory if evidence appeared to show it to be wrong, yet we can show many of these words to be 'wrong' (by word-part breakdown or by use morph) and everyone seems to just shrug and say "yeah it doesn't really describe what hat is, but F*** it- it is just too much trouble to find or create a word that actually means *X*."

So I ask the crowd:

Why do fields that highly value precision in so many ways continue to use very imprecise language having had ample opportunity to 'clean up' their specific field's language?

Comment: Sorry, this question isn't really well-formed for this SE. But even so, what may seem imprecise when read by a lay person may have a specific meaning in the argot of a profession or scientific discipline.

Comment: How might I better form the question? Tried pretty hard to first describe then ask, so am troubled it seems not well formed. Is "Why do fields requiring precision retain imprecise terms and words?" better?

Comment: There is no way around it. Even if a new word is invented it would suffer the same fate as you described. And look at the use of the word **literally** which is supposed to be precise but is mis-used, such as "I was literally crushed".

Comment: Common use and abuse is outside the scope of my question, though I wish we were ALL more accurate with the words we use. And there IS a way around it, at least within isolated fields. Usually referred to as jargon, I guess, but it is possible to put in place accurate, or at least specific, words for concepts within a field.

Comment: But you already stated that the usage of "irrational" morphed. Nobody can prevent that from happening.

Comment: @111936 - It's just that there isn't likely to be an answer that isn't opinion-based, which would be off-topic here. The reason is that for the users of the argot in question, they likely *are* using unambiguous language. They understand each other well. It's only looking from the outside that it might seem imprecise.

Comment: Just added a section on scientific method not being applied to their own behaviours.

Comment: @JimMack - IF you and I decided to use "meat" to mean "vegetable," and stuck to it - we'd understand each other. But anyone else would be mighty confused. Some might get it after a while, but most would depart with the wrong understanding. So yes, the current USE is understood. As would any new use be. But the question remains open - why isn't more precise and accurate language developed and used?

Comment: Re the question edit: terms *are* changed in response to the changing understanding. Which means that a more accurate language *is* developed and used.

Comment: @111936 The language is **very** precise to those that use it. It is not going to change, because the current usage is well-established. There is a body of work using the established language that would be obsoleted by such change. Revolutions in language are extremely rare.

Comment: Better example of what I'm questioning is likening it to Cockney slang. Internally it all makes sense, but from the outside it's ridiculous (and hilarious, often). They are well  aware that they are misusing the language (that's the point of it) and revel in making each other make multiple associative steps to attain meaning. MANY things they say become equivalent terms in their brains, so the associative steps get skipped. This doesn't mean that the associative steps aren't mandatory, just that the listener has already done them. (Cont...)

Comment: In the sciences and maths, this is also true - but then they try to teach NEW LEARNERS of the subjects IN THE COCKNEY. Most won't be able to make sense of the cockney (especially if they are not English) and walk away baffled and without the information that was conveyed. THIS is my main thrust.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Please expand a bit more on the final sentence of your comment and make that into an answer? "There is a body of work using the established language that would be obsoleted by such change. Revolutions in language are extremely rare." Or maybe someone else would flesh that last sentence out and post it as an answer?

Comment: What a misguided rant! First of all, many many terms are very well chosen to agre with their meaning. One source of many relatively newly coined terms is the area of Algebraic geometry. Grothendieck, one of the main culprits of many of the new concepts is famed for his use of very precise language. So many very abstract concepts in algebraic geometry got names that are quite visually similar to what the concept is: **stalk**, **sheaf**, **spectrum**, **blowup**, etc.

Comment: The diametrically opposite way of choosing names also happens. But this is in itself not a bad thing. If you are denoting something so new and hard to describe the best could be to give it a name that has nothing to do with what it is. In this way you only need to treat the name like a blank or empty name, which just got filled with meaning. The problem with that some might have with this is that not everyone is prepared in the skill of abstraction, removing oneself from any previous meaning or preconception and work only with what is actually given or postulated.

Comment: An example of the latter is the concept of **coquecigrew**, a portmanteau of rooster and crane in French.

Comment: The idea of abstraction is particularly important in mathematics, in which it is essential the fact that what is relevant from the basic objects of some axiomatic system are they way the axioms of that system prescribe their behavior and not any extra intuitive property that their names might suggest. For example, in Euclidean geometry it is important that any two points have a line in common (among other axioms). It is not relevant anything else that you might image that "a point", "a line" or "in common" means, but only that the axiom is a true statement.

Comment: This allows any theorem proven in the axiomatic system to hold true for any type of object that you might want to call "point", "line" and relation that you might want to call "have in common", as long as they satisfy the axioms. From which the theorem was derived. For example, a point could be actually a pair of antipodal points in a sphere, a line could be actually any maximal circle on a sphere, and "in common" might be that the circle passes through the points. These objects are not what you normally call "points", "lines" and "in common", yet they satisfy all the axioms of plane geometry.

Comment: "React" does not mean "act again" the [Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/react) has a number of very specific meanings including ones from both physics and chemistry but the basic one is _Act in response to something; respond in a particular way_. This is the souce of the chemical, and physical meanings and is only indirectly related to "do again". Rather it imples that the action is a respose to presented conditions.

Comment: Except for the so called Euclid's fifth postulate. Therefore, any theorem that you prove in plane geometry that holds for what you normally call points and lines and which doesn't require the fifth postulate to be proven, also holds for those new objects. The intuition that one can derive from the common use of their names can occasionally aid thinking, but also often times it is a hindrance.

Comment: @mama I guess the point is that using (reasonably) recognisable terms _more often_ aids understanding than is a hindrance. This ties in with OP's comment "_this strange use of English [...] is the primary reason I found maths so challenging_" ... it might be somewhat confusing if some everyday terms aren't used _exactly_ the same as everyday, but I'm sure would be far less confusing than having to invent a completely new term for every concept (think trying to follow Euclid using random terms like _jintakis_ and _hebroves_ instead of points/lines).

Comment: @111936, you are falling into the [etymological fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy). Words mean what they mean, not what you might think they meant from looking at their origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very interesting question and gets to the heart of a lot of problems with understanding the meanings of words.

You say that words used in mathematics and science are vague and distort the real meaning of the original word. One half of this the case, the other the opposite.

Math and science use existing terms or invents new ones from existing parts in order to label new concepts. If an existing word is used, there is sometimes an attempt to have it be evocative or metaphorical but often sadly falls very short, distorting the original meaning. Irrational numbers aren't at all irrational (to our usual idea of that word). Imaginary ones likewise; its replacement 'complex' also metaphorical but closer to the true technical meaning is only part way there. Similarly in other sciences, 'power', 'force', 'capacitance', any technical term is its own thing only suggested by the informal generic term.

But math and science vague? No, that's exactly what they're not. The whole point of  knowledge is to reduce vagueness. The vocabulary that is used for the new precise concepts is often Fixed. The term is then not vague *at all*. When used in the technical context, the label is as precise as possible. This is called

> [stipulative definition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/definitions/).

Whatever preconceptions one may have of a vocabulary item is only a nice story, but the label (in the technical context) has its meaning **stipulated**, said to be only attached to the precise concepts. 'Irrational' may mean informally something vague like crazy, but in math it means *exactly* not expressible as a fraction. That is very precise and not vague at all.

From the outside, when you don't know what these stipulated meanings are supposed to be, when you're just being exposed to them and haven't learned them properly, they seem just as vague as the informal terms, or really, even more vague because the concept hasn't been learned well. Technical meanings don't need to be cleaned up because they're cleaning up the informal definitions (or even making up totally new but very precise ones).

---

Think of the language of math and science as a foreign language with a lot of false friends. The words in your language may be very specific and the words in math in science may be very specific, but because the same sounding word means different things in the two languages, it feels like those foreigners aren't using it right and can't be pinned down to a coherent meaning.

---

TL;DR 
Math and science terms are the least vague of terms; they are intentionally made ('stipulated') to have particular meanings. It is the learning of these meanings that leaves them imprecise at the beginning.

So don't take things so literally. An everyday word used in a technical capacity has become much more specific. The vagueness is in the informal usage or being early in the learning of the technical meaning.

Comment: There's a lot to say here, stuff about the [etymological fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy) (meanings drift, so the meaning of a word is not necessarily the same as it used to be or to what the combo of its parts is), and that mental concepts/ideas are not the same thing as words that we label them with. Those are alluded to but are merely supportive to the main point about stipulative definitions.

Comment: 1) I'll accept this an an answer, it seems to sum up the other commentary and gives context to those comments above.

Comment: 2) I fully accept and live in the real world where words have no consistency of meaning, I thought I'd made that clear enough before. But I still do wish there was any actual consistency or some clear decoding ability to the language so that this process of "re-learning words" to learn math was not needed.. Terrifying to see this view is tied to the third reich (vie wikipedia about etymological fallacy).

Comment: Which view is tied to the Third Reich? That people don't stick to the original meaning of a word or that people consider that a mistake/only one of many viable meanings?

Comment: The wikipedia page for etymological fallacy cites a reference that itself discusses this fallacy in relationship to the Nazi's supremacy/purity ideas. So now I fear my attitude about hating ambiguous words and desiring consistency in word-part/word-origin/usage/etc is somehow attached in some people's minds to being a psycho racist. Lovely.

Comment: Don't take everything so literally; Hitler was a non-smoking vegetarian, so are non-smokers and vegetarians evil? Just because there's a link there doesn't mean that the two are linked in any meaningful way. People put all sorts of crap in Wikipedia.

Comment: I think the label 'fallacy' in etymological fallacy is a bit hyperbolic especially since some words _do_ mean what they used to mean 2000 years ago, just pronounced funny. It's not obvious but now we can realize that: words change in meaning, words can have more than one meaning, words can have one of those meanings or a new one be technical (stipulated to be the case just for technical usage).

Comment: Perhaps I'm picking nits, but complex numbers aren't a replacement for imaginary ones.  They are a composite, having both a real and imaginary part (either of which can be zero), and so include both reals and imaginaries.